# iOS Crash Log reading

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I'm developing an app which uses an external accessory and the app crashes at some point. The hardest thing to debug is an app that crashes and the device can't be connected to Xcode.

The crash log I'm getting is not symbolised and I didn't succeeded in making it more clear.

Can anyone give me a hit in what is wrong with my code from the crash log attached.

```
Incident Identifier: 9BB6134A-68AF-4D88-9DF4-E1AB5F00F429
CrashReporter Key:   7c5ffd5961e66395d76785cd412baf0761515cbb
Hardware Model:      iPad5,4
Process:             reFlash [666]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E98396D-5D6B-4FF1-8992-389A73E4A17D/reFlash.app/reFlash
Identifier:          com.softescu.reflash
Version:             1 (1.06)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.softescu.reflash [663]


Date/Time:           2017-05-17 17:06:26.2257 +0300
Launch Time:         2017-05-17 17:05:51.8520 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18a2451b8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x188c7c55c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18a245100 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
3   CoreFoundation                  0x18a13fd90 -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 168
4   reFlash                         0x1000a3d10 0x10006c000 + 228624
5   reFlash                         0x1000a3224 0x10006c000 + 225828
6   reFlash                         0x100085448 0x10006c000 + 103496
7   reFlash                         0x10008914c 0x10006c000 + 119116
8   reFlash                         0x1000cc41c 0x10006c000 + 394268
9   reFlash                         0x1000cb704 0x10006c000 + 390916
10  ExternalAccessory               0x1979f5ff8 -[EAInputStream _streamEventTrigger] + 504
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18a1f2b5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
12  CoreFoundation                  0x18a1f24a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
13  CoreFoundation                  0x18a1f00a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
14  CoreFoundation                  0x18a11e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
15  Foundation                      0x18ac5b26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
16  Foundation                      0x18acafaa0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
17  reFlash                         0x100088d88 0x10006c000 + 118152
18  Foundation                      0x18ad58e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1892d9850 _pthread_body + 240
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1892d9760 _pthread_start + 284
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1892d6d94 thread_start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f4ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a11e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   GraphicsServices                0x000000018bbd2198 GSEventRunModal + 180
6   UIKit                           0x000000019015e7fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
7   UIKit                           0x0000000190159534 UIApplicationMain + 208
8   reFlash                         0x000000010009f4c8 0x10006c000 + 210120
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001891015b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f4ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a11e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018ac5b26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018ac7bdd0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x0000000190ad2c38 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018ad58e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9850 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9760 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d94 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  GAIThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f4ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a11e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018ac5b26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018acafaa0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   reFlash                         0x00000001000afe0c 0x10006c000 + 278028
8   Foundation                      0x000000018ad58e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9850 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9760 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d94 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189213014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892db450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000189187400 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000188c512d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000188c6b688 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 44
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000188c6b234 __cxa_rethrow + 144
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000188c7c71c objc_exception_rethrow + 44
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a11e32c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
8   Foundation                      0x000000018ac5b26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
9   Foundation                      0x000000018acafaa0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
10  reFlash                         0x0000000100088d88 0x10006c000 + 118152
11  Foundation                      0x000000018ad58e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9850 _pthread_body + 240
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9760 _pthread_body + 0
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d94 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018921323c __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f9468 __CFSocketManager + 640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9850 _pthread_body + 240
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9760 _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d94 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891f4ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a1f01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a11e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018a923a70 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6   Foundation                      0x000000018ad58e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9850 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d9760 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d94 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001892d6d88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700fb4b1
    x4: 0x0000000188c6f963   x5: 0x000000016e292ab0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000340
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000031  x11: 0xffffffffffffffff
   x12: 0x000000018919e772  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000188c96d54  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000016e293000  x21: 0x000000016e292ab0  x22: 0x00000001af2bcbb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000170018750  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016e292a10   lr: 0x00000001892db450
    sp: 0x000000016e2929f0   pc: 0x0000000189213014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: in attached log we can see that your app crashes on `substringWithRange` while parsing data from `EAInputStream`. And it is all useful information here

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was suspecting that substringWithRange may be the problem, but my app is performing a lot of identically operations. Sometimes it crashes after 200, sometimes after 400 operations, never the same. I'm not parsing data from EAInputScream, I'm just reading a file and getting particular characters.

Comment: So you need to found way to reproduce this crash in development environment with attached debugger, in other cases it will be really hard to catch it